# Seeking alternative to ArcGIS Pro Split tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, splitting, suitability-analysis

Using ArcGIS Pro for references:

I have a polygon feature converted from raster that covers a large area produced by a suitability analysis. There are a lot of little shapes (11,932 total) within the feature with the important values of 1 and 0.

For this same area, I have all the parcels in the area (9,870 total).

I am being asked to use the Split tool (by polygon) for the suitability feature by polygon (with the parcel feature) using the unique ID of the parcel. This process results in all of the parcels being being exported as their own feature class, but with all the multiple shapes that have split it from the suitability feature.

Then I am being asked to merge all the individual feature files into one.

The problem is that these are both very large features and the split tool takes considerable time to do this. Then trying to merge all the feature files into one, usually results in "not responding" or a crash.

Is there a much simpler and faster way (to get the same result) do this then this process?

This is just one of several suitability feature files that need to be processed this way.

Comment: Are (many of) the suitability polygonds adjacent? Would it make any difference if you dissolve them on the suitability value and then overlay the dissolved layer with the parcels (sorry as a QGIS user, I do not know how to do a dissolve in arcgis, but it should be possible to find)

Comment: What format is your data, if a shapefile have you added a spatial index? If this is your scenario this is why you should be using data in a file geodatabase.

Comment: You could try visiting each polygon in your split layer using an ArcPy cursor or ModelBuilder and use it to clip one at a time.

Comment: I dont understand fully but what if you intersect then dissolve?

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy

    # Set the workspace environment
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb"
    
    # Input and output feature classes
    suitability_feature = "Suitability"
    parcels_feature = "Parcels"
    output_feature = "OutputFeature"
    dissolved_feature = "DissolvedOutput"
    dissolve_field = "Parcel_ID"  # Change this to your actual field name
    
    # Spatial Join (Split)
    output_join = arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(target_features=parcels_feature,
                                             join_features=suitability_feature,
                                             out_feature_class=output_feature,
                                             join_type="KEEP_COMMON")
    
    # Dissolve (Merge)
    arcpy.management.Dissolve(output_join, dissolved_feature, dissolve_field)
```

DM me on Instagram if you need more help
@andersonjj